# How do I fix my code about a script that stopped working?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that generates an item code when the ‍`combo-boxes‍‍‍` are selected.

For example, if `Computer Equipment` and `Printer` is selected, the script would generate the code ‍`CEPR000001‍` and display it on the textbox. 
It was working last March but now it suddenly stopped working. Can someone help me with this?

Script:

```
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}

function getAssetCode() {
    document.getElementById("code2").value = $('#class').find(":selected").data('value') + 1;

    var x = document.getElementById("cat").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("class").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("code2").value;         

    var result = pad(z, 6);

    var xyz = x.concat(y,result);

    $('#code').value(xyz);
}
```

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="assetcategory" id="cat" required>
    <option value="CE">Computer Equipment</option>
    <option value="OP">Other Properties</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="assetclass" id="class" onchange="getAssetCode()" required>
    <option value="PR" data-value="1">Printer</option>
    <option value="CP" data-value="2">Mobile Phone</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="assetcode1" id="code" disabled>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="assetcode2" id="code2" hidden>
```

Comment: The console indicates that your problem is in the line: `$('#code').value(xyz);`.  JavaScript is expecting the `.value` property of your `#code` element to hold the name of a  function (but I'm not sure you ever assign any value to the `.value` property at all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to include jQuery in your question, not sure if this is already done but add the following line to head

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Secondly, you need to change :

```
$('#code').value(xyz);
```

to

```
$('#code').val(xyz);
```

Working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/fcozp36v/

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `$('#code').val(xyz);` instead of `$('#code').value(xyz)` in JQuery

```js
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}

function getAssetCode() {
debugger;
    document.getElementById("code2").value = $('#class').find(":selected").data('value') + 1;

    var x = document.getElementById("cat").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("class").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("code2").value;         

    var result = pad(z, 6);

    var xyz = x.concat(y,result);

    $('#code').val(xyz);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" name="assetcategory" id="cat" required>
    <option value="CE">Computer Equipment</option>
    <option value="OP">Other Properties</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="assetclass" id="class" onchange="getAssetCode()" required>
    <option value="PR" data-value="1">Printer</option>
    <option value="CP" data-value="2">Mobile Phone</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="assetcode1" id="code" disabled>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="assetcode2" id="code2" hidden>
```

`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'd take note of this next time.